# How can I refactor my code to return a collection of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

```
def read_data(service_client):
    data = list_data(domain, realm) # This returns a data frame 
    building_data = []
    building_names = {}
    all_buildings = {}

    for elem in data.iterrows():
        building = elem[1]['building_name']
        region_id = elem[1]['region_id']
        bandwith = elem[1]['bandwith']
        building_id = elem[1]['building_id']

       return {
       'Building': building,
       'Region Id': region_id,
       'Bandwith': bandwith,
       'Building Id': building_id,
       }
```

Basically I am able to return a single dictionary value upon a iteration here in this example. I have tried printing it as well and others.

I am trying to find a way to store multiple dictionary values on each iteration and return it, instead of just returning one.. Does anyone know any ways to achieve this?

Comment: Your return is inside the for loop, you probably want to append to a list in that for loop, and then return that list *after* the loop.

Comment: This return one itteration as well

Answer (score 0):

You may replace your for-loop with the following to get all dictionaries in a `list`.

```
naming = {
    'building_name': 'Building',
    'region_id': 'Region Id',
    'bandwith': 'Bandwith',
    'building_id': 'Building Id',
}


return [ 
    row[list(naming.values())].to_dict() 
        for idx, row in data.rename(naming, axis=1).iterrows() 
]
```

Comment: Looks like this solution may work; however, I am getting the error ** KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['Bandwith'], dtype='object'). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike**

Comment: The error says this column `Bandwith` doesn't exist but `Bandwith` was based on your question. Can you check your data column names and make the corrections? Should it be `Bandwidth` instead?